# angular http post json object's doesn't deserialize properly by mvc4

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my Angularjs service I have this code:

```
$http.post(baseUrl + "Location/SaveBulk/", { "BulkPrice": run }, { cache: false });
```

Here is my MVC code where I try to deserialize it.

```
 <HttpPost>
    Public Function SaveBulk(ByVal BulkPrice As Object) As ActionResult

        Dim req As Stream = Request.InputStream
        req.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
        Dim json As String = New StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd()
        req.Close()
        Dim objModel As BulkPrice = Nothing

        Try

            objModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of BulkPrice)(json)

            'do stuff

        Catch

            ' Try and handle malformed POST body
            Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        End Try

        'do stuff
        Return View("Index")

    End Function
```

My BULKPRICE class is as below

```
Public Class BulkPrice

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="ServiceProvider is required")>
    Public Property ServiceProviderId As Integer

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Zone is required")>
    Public Property LocationZoneId As Integer

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Charge type is required")>
    Public Property ChargeTypeId As Integer

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Comments are required")>
    Public Property Comments As String

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Charge amount is required")>
    <RegularExpression("^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d*)?\s*$", ErrorMessage:="Charge amount must be greater than zero")>
    Public Property Charge As Decimal

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Start date is required")>
    <RegularExpression("^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{4})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{4})$|^$")>
    Public Property StartDate As DateTime

    Public Property RunDays As List(Of RunDay)

    Public Sub New()

        RunDays = New List(Of RunDay)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Fiddler request is as below
[image]

InputStream reads data properly but DeserializeObject() doesn't deserialize it properly.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: You can just bind direct to your model - `Public Function SaveBulk(ByVal BulkPrice As BulkPrice) As ActionResult`

Comment: What is the error you get? Also you don't need JSON.stringify while passing object to post?

Comment: I am using partial view in modal popup. have to do some validations and then have to call angular service to send it back to server.

Comment: When I send it via $http.get(), it works and serializes but with post, it doesn't.